# instant search without dropdown using jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to search a text and get the result in a html table, can I use jquery UI autocomplete and render the result in my own place instead of showing it like a dropdown?

Comment: Can you please supply any code / examples you have already tried?

Comment: If you do not want to render the result in what UI autocomplete give you then why to use it? Why not to use ajax, and get back json? You can find many examples of how to do it on the Internet.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What kind of results are going into "your own place"? If searching a list of cities, the jQUI autocomplete will display all cities containing the user-typed letters in a dropdown -- are you showing that same list in a table cell, or do you only show part of such a list? `Please provide more details about what you are doing.`

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have a code because I'm starting to use it. I need to search for something in a textbox, go to the server, execute a stored procedure and return data in a html table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to make sure that the `.ui-autocomplete` is never visible and then you need to use the `response` event from the autocomplete widget to get the data and build your table

http://jsfiddle.net/KKgvK/